# Is there some way to force 'updatedisplaylist' immediately rather than at later some point

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

In flex component life cycle, after we make some change in a components property, invalidation methods schedules  a call to methods like `commitProperties`, `updateDisplayList`, etc for some later time. I need to call the `updateDisplayList` instantaneously. Is there some direct way to do this. 
Currently, both the labels are changed simultaneously after completion of the loop. Instead I need it to work like this, to first render the updated 'myButton1' label then enter the loop and then update myButton2's label. I know, it is elastic race track issue, but isn't there some way to achieve this ?

```
myButton1.label = 'New Label1' ;
// Some logic to forcibly make the screen reflect it

for (var i:int = 0; i < 500 ; i ++){
//a dummy loop

}

myButton2.label = 'New Label2' ;
```

Comment: A helpful link : "http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/?p=220&cpage=1#comment-118964"

Comment: Another useful link (for all purposes): http://www.slideshare.net/rjowen/component-life-cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the label for myButton1, then put the remaining code into a separate method and call that method using callLater:

```
private function foo():void {
    myButton1.label = 'New Label1';
    this.callLater(bar);
}

private function bar():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 500 ; i ++){ //a dummy loop
    }
    myButton2.label = 'New Label2';
}
```

This way myButton1 will update to show the new label before going into your loop since callLater doesn't call bar until after the event queue is cleared, giving myButton1 a chance to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `myButton1.validateNow()` but it's use is discouraged, for you may end up having the same component update itself multiple times on the same frame.

Answer (score 2):

Use [validateNow()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#validateNow%28%29) .  But, I would use it sparingly.  using invalidateDisplayList() will force updateDisplayList() to run on the next renderer event.

A render event happens on each frame.  24 frames happen each second by default for Flex.  Are you sure need to change these values quicker?

Comment: Thanks for the help www.Flextras.com. I wonder if increasing the frame rate should be a good optoin. How will it affect overall, specially the elastic race track ?

Comment: It is something I would experiment with before changing it in a production app.  Some people have improved performance by changing the frame rate; others have not been so lucky.

Answer (score 0):

invalidateDisplayList()  or valdiateNow() will do it for you however excess of using these will end up memory leaks.